# XML - XSL : PDF generation with limited rows per page

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement to generated PDF from XML using XSL style sheet. I have more number of rows from XML., so in my PDF i have to display only 4 rows per page.

It like, if i have 10 rows in my XML, in my PDF it should display like 4 per page and totally 3 PDF pages and 4 per pages.

Page 1 : 4 rows
Page 2 : 4 rows
Page 3 : 2 rows

Please find my XML :

```
<receipt>
    <order>
        <page>
            <line_number>1</line_number>
            <product_code>S10</product_code>
            <line_number>2</line_number>
            <product_code>S20</product_code>
            <line_number>3</line_number>
            <product_code>S92</product_code>
            <line_number>4</line_number>
            <product_code>S31</product_code>
            <line_number>5</line_number>
            <product_code>S31</product_code>
       </page>
       <page>
            <line_number>6</line_number>
            <product_code>S31</product_code>
            <line_number>7</line_number>
            <product_code>S31</product_code>
            <line_number>8</line_number>
            <product_code>S31</product_code>
            <line_number>9</line_number>
            <product_code>S31</product_code>
            <line_number>10</line_number>
            <product_code>S31</product_code>
        </page>
    </order>
</receipt>
```

Please find XSL template, right now, it displaying all 10 rows in a single page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
                              xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="date">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/receipt">
        <html>
            <head>
            <style>@page {size: a4 landscape;}</style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <table >
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th >Line</th>
                            <th>Item Code</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <xsl:for-each select="order/page/line_number">
                            <tr style="font-size: 9px; ">
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::product_code[1]" /></td>
                            </tr>
                 </xsl:for-each>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                <br />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that with HTML then, as I already told you in a similar question, one way is to generate as many `tbody` sections as you want pages and to use CSS `page-break-after: always` for the `tbody`s:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="rows-per-page" select="4"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

    <xsl:template match="/receipt">
        <html>
            <head>
            <style>
                @page {size: a4 landscape;}
                tbody { page-break-after: always; }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <table >
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th >Line</th>
                            <th>Item Code</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="order/page/line_number" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $rows-per-page">
                      <tbody>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                      </tbody>
                 </xsl:for-each-group>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="line_number">
        <tr style="font-size: 9px;">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::product_code[1]" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rM7

That example uses XSLT 2/3's for-each-group to wrap the wanted number of items in a `tbody` but with some more effort the same can be done in XSLT 1 if needed. You can run XSLT 2 or 3 with Saxon 9 for Java or .NET or C/C++.